# How to compress multiple affiliation numbers?

Tags: revtex, journal-publishing, affiliation

The affiliations of the authors are by default referenced with single numbers **1,2,3**. How is it possible to get compressed numbers, i.e.**1-3** as in the picture ? Answers are of interest that use classes `Revtex4`, `article`, or `report`.

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation A}
\affiliation{Affiliation B}
\affiliation{Affiliation C}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like that. But be aware that `revtex` is a quite complex class and changes can affect other places. Normally you should better leave such classes alone or sent a feature request to the maintainers instead of messing with their internals.

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\def\@affil@present@script{%
 \let\@tempa\@empty
 \@affil@present@script@{\@affilID@temp}\relax
}%
\def\@affil@present@script@#1{%
 \tl_set:Nx\l_tmpa_tl{\tl_item:Nn#1{1}}
 \tl_set:Nx\l_tmpb_tl{\tl_item:Nn#1{-1}}
 \tl_if_eq:NNTF\l_tmpa_tl\l_tmpb_tl
   {\textsuperscript{\l_tmpa_tl}}
   {\textsuperscript{\l_tmpa_tl--\l_tmpb_tl}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation A}
\affiliation{Affiliation B}
\affiliation{Affiliation C}
\author{AuthorB}
\affiliation{Affiliation D}
\affiliation{Affiliation E}
\affiliation{Affiliation F}
\author{AuthorC}
\affiliation{Affiliation G}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```